# PDO::Prepare safety

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read that the `PDO::Prepare` function creates a *safe* query. Does this mean escape characters don't need to be manually literalised? Such as the backslash character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*No* it absolutely does not mean that.  What you read is misleading.

There is a difference between a "prepared statement" and a "parameterized query."  You want the latter for sanitation purposes.

For example:

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col1 = $USER_PROVIDED_VALUE");
```

is not safe at all even though it is prepared.  Instead, you have to do this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col1 = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($USER_PROVIDED_VALUE));
```

Preparing the query isn't going to do anything for you in terms of security if you do not properly parameterize it.